# creating an href with a variable url

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**Scenario :**

- Trying to create a webpage with a variable url location.
- Currently the code is designed to send you to a file called asdf.txt
  **however I'd like to be able to change the url from asdf.txt to
  somethingelse.txt** for example.
- Below is the code as it is now, and
  below that is my unsuccessful attempt to change the file name.

Please suggest. 
Thanks.

**this is the code as it is right now :**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

class NameForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<a href="asdf.txt" onclick="$('a').hide()">this is a link</a>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <NameForm />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

</script>
</body>
```

**New Code :**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

class NameForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let name = "asdf" // this would be a more complicated proccess
        return (<a href=name+".txt" onclick="$('a').hide()">this is a link</a>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <NameForm />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: have you tried `return <a href={\`${name}.txt\`} onclick="$('a').hide()">this is a link</a>`?

Comment: if you make that an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In react, there is no HTML, but only JSX. Please enclose any variable usage in JSX between `{}`.

Please try this:

```
return <a href={`${name}.txt`} onclick="$('a').hide()">this is a link</a>
```